# C# sql query and datatable with no-date format to get difference

Tags: c#

I take with SQL query 2 columns - 1st is only with numbers, 2nd is with date. But values from 1st column are date too, but without ":" and spaces (non-date format).

I need 3rd column in datatable which give me difference between 1st and 2nd time.

Can you give me advice how to proceed ? I tried manually add ":", I cannot change SQL database - only read and input into datatable.

```cs
SqlDataAdapter test = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con2);
test.Fill(dt);
dt.Columns.Add("Real", typeof(int));
dt.Columns["Real"].SetOrdinal(5);
DataTable distinctTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable( /*distinct*/ true);
dataGridView1.DataSource = distinctTable;
distinctTable.Columns["Real"].SetOrdinal(5);
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].Visible = false;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

int a = 0;
foreach (DataRow d in distinctTable.Rows)
{ 
   try
   {
       DateTime da = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells["Real"].Value.ToString(), "yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       d["Real"] = da;
       ++a;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       ++a;
       continue;
   }
}
```

Example table:

```
   Column1           Column2
_______________|____________________
20170707060713 | 2017-07-07 06:13:43
20170707061326 | 2017-07-07 06:21:16
20170707062059 | 2017-07-07 06:28:54
20170707062837 | 2017-07-07 06:36:22
20170707063605 | 2017-07-07 06:43:50
20170707064333 | 2017-07-07 06:51:08
```

Comment: you need to first convert the values into a DateTime, then you need to look up how to convert DateTime values into `TimeStamp` or you can look up `TimeSpan` please show us also what you have tried on your own besides posting an Image and explaining what it is you need.. also google how to add columns to a datatable..

Comment: Grab each row, parse the first column into a DateTime `DateTime.TryParse`, then compare the new DateTime object to the DateTime in the second column.  Then insert whatever you need to via a simple SQL query

Comment: No code?  Show (not tell) us what you have done and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following SQL query converts numeric (bigint) column to SQL DateTime format, and calculate diff between two dates:

```
DECLARE @Test table(num bigint, dte datetime);
INSERT INTO @Test(num, dte) VALUES(20170707060713, '2017-07-05 18:36:58')

SELECT num,
       dte,
      DATEDIFF(hour, dte, convert(DATETIME, substring(CAST(num AS NVARCHAR), 0, 9)
                        +' '+substring(CAST(num AS NVARCHAR), 9, 2)
                        +':'+substring(CAST(num AS NVARCHAR), 11, 2)
                        +':'+substring(CAST(num AS NVARCHAR), 13, 2))) AS dteFromNum
    from @Test;
```

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01fa7/5)

Comment: @Tom, this is correct behavior: we are calculating diff between two dates in hours. If you need difference in another values, just change "hour" to value you want (minute, second, day, etc). [DATEDIFF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

Comment: Ah. Perfect ! :)